# Laravel not reaching update method and returns edit view again – route wrong

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

When I click Save on my edit view, my routing brings back my edit view instead of my index view and my update method is never reached.

I noticed that I reach the update method if I remove “UsersRequest $request” from the method parameters. Not sure why, and if it’s related, but I need $request to do my update (see controller code below):

Routes:

```
Route::get('/users', 'UsersController@index')->name('users.index');
Route::patch('/users/{id}', 
[
    'as' => 'users.update',
    'uses' => 'UsersController@update'
]);
Route::get('/users/{id}/edit', 'UsersController@edit');
```

Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests\UsersRequest;


//public function update($id, UsersRequest $request)
public function update($id)   //- with $request removed, the index view is displayed
{       
    $user = \Auth::user();
    $user->update($request->all());

    return view('users.index');
}
```

Edit view:

```
{!! Form::model($user, ['method' => 'PATCH', 'action' => [ 'UsersController@update', 'user' => $user->id ] ]) !!}


{!! Form::submit('Save', ['class'=>'btn primary']) !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Network after save button clicked

```
URL                                                 Protocol    Method  Result      
/myapp/public/users/1                               HTTP        POST    302     Goes for the update route
http://000.000.000.000/myapp/public/users/1/edit    HTTP        POST    200     Redirects to the edit route??
```

.env

```
 APP_URL=http://000.000.000.000/myapp/public
```

Comment: You probably want the `PATCH` request to return a `redirect` and not a `view`

Comment: Just tried `return redirect('users');` same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're failing whatever validation is present in your `UsersRequest` form request. When the validation fails, it redirects you back to where you came from, which is your edit view. Your edit view should be updated to show the validation errors so that your users know what fields need to be fixed.

The reason it works when you remove the `UsersRequest $request` parameter is that the validation is no longer being performed.

Comment: You rock @patricus. Fixed. I was validating the email field, but it's not part of the fields in my edit view.